# Ant compile of Android APK Cannot run program "android.bat" but it exists

Tags: android, ant, temenos-quantum

Using the KonyOne platform (essentially an Eclipse plug-in), I am getting an error from the ANT build script stating that it cannot find "android.bat" (in directory "D:\GoogleAndroid\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools), but when I search that directory, the file is there and non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the Android emulator and build set up can be annoying, but there is a pattern to it:

- First off, make sure from the Windows command line that you would be able to call the android.bat.  So from C:\ prompt, type: `android.bat` and the Android SDK manager should start.  If this does not work, then you need to update your Windows Path.
- Here is my path:

  Path=%JAVA_HOME%;C:\KonyOne\ImageMagick;%ANT_HOME%;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools

  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk

  ANDROID_SDK_HOME=C:\Android\sdk
- Make sure your project has the Android sdk path set.  Right click the project, go to Properties, select Kony Dev Studio, Build, and the Android home should be the path to the SDK folder ( in my case, it was C:\Android\sdk )
- Be sure that you close your windows command prompt window and restart Kony Studio to get the Path changes to apply ( this is a Windows thing )

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been through many permutations of re-installing -- including java JDK / JRE from 1.6 to 1.7 to 1.6.  Each step fixed one problem, but a new one opened.  In the end, I had to downlevel Android SDK *TOOLS* from 19.x to 18.x.  That appears to have resolved my issue in total and I can build my Android App using Kony Studio -- once again.  I will review my environment against your comments to confirm that it is conforming.

Comment: Yes, there was a Google-side issue with 19.x that may / may not have been resolved ( depending on the moon, sun, stars ), but definitely 18.x is the current "good to go" version.  For the record, I have heard 19.x has been fixed but have not bothered to go through the process of testing it myself.  Also be careful when going through the Android SDK tool, as I've found that it keeps trying to auto-install the 19.x tools for me by automatically checking the checkbox when I go into the SDK manager, so I have to manually tell it "no, don't want it yet"